# Filter out anything but interactive form fields in PDF's

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm looking for a way to filter out all objects apart from interactive form fields in PDF files.
The programming language isn't too important, but it would would love if I could do it from the Linux command line but I'm pretty much open to anything.
E.g. choose an pdf input file, and output a new pdf file with only the interactive form fields from the first.

The ultimate goal is to be able to take an already printed but unfilled form , and print only the content of the filled in form fields onto it.

The closest I've gotten is by using ghostscript:

```
gs -o outfile.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFILTERTEXT -dFILTERIMAGE infile.pdf
```

But that still leaves a lot of lines in my case, as well as an image despite `-dFILTERIMAGE`.
There's also a `-dFILTERVECTOR`-option but sadly it removes the formfields as well.

Comment: For an arbitrary general purpose pdf library: clear the contents entry of every page.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, so you mean that everything apart from the form fields resides in a content element in every page so I just have to remove those? Could you give an example on how to do that with any library?

Comment: Sorry, for some reasons I overlooked your response. Would a Java or C# based example be ok?

Comment: No worries, happens to me too. Yes, absolutely. Either one would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to filter out all objects apart from interactive form fields in PDF files.

First and foremost you have to get rid of the static page content. Using an arbitrary general purpose pdf library you can do that by clearing the contents entry of every page.

E.g. using the Java version of iText7 this can be done as follows:

```java
try (
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(RESULT);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter)
) {
    for (int pageNr = 1; pageNr <= pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages(); pageNr++) {
        PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDocument.getPage(pageNr);
        pdfPage.getPdfObject().remove(PdfName.Contents);
        pdfPage.getPdfObject().setModified();
    }
}
```

*([RemoveContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/RemoveContent.java#L38) test `testRemoveAllPageContentStreams`)*

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I just tried it and it works great for the documents I've tried it with!